# ArrayList is not initializing properly in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am using the `ArrayList` in my application.
I declared `List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();` globally but the products are not adding into this list because `productList` is showing as `null` instead of empty array list.

Below is my code:

```
Map<String, List<Product>> productListMap = productSuggestBox.getValueMap();

List<Product> queriedProductList = productListMap.get("productList");

long productId = Long.valueOf(productSuggestBoxValue);

for (Product product : queriedProductList) {
    if (product.getId() == productId) {
        productList.add(product);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: I removed the 'gwt' tag because, as it is written, this appears to be just a Java question with nothing having to do with GWT.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas We don't know if that's what his code actually says. I wouldn't change it to say something else.

Comment: @msnaidu is it possible to include the relevant snippet of the whole java class instead of just the method were you are accessing the list? Thanks

Comment: So by "globally", you mean that this is a field in your class?  Where and when is that initialized?

Comment: yes, that is my class variable.  public class SalesInvoiceWidget extends Composite { List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>(); // above code }

Comment: Show the complete code, and where exactly it doesn't behave like you think it should (what you expect, what happens instead)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to piece together the structure of the code from the fragments you provided:

```
public class SalesInvoiceWidget extends Composite { 
    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();

    // ...

    private void someMethod() {
        Map<String, List<Product>> productListMap = 
                productSuggestBox.getValueMap();

        List<Product> queriedProductList = productListMap.get("productList");

        long productId = Long.valueOf(productSuggestBoxValue);

        for (Product product : queriedProductList) {
            if (product.getId() == productId) {
                productList.add(product);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Assuming that reconstruction above is completely is correct, then the only way that `productList` can be `null` is that somewhere in your code (not shown above!), you are *assigning* `null` to `productList`.

Another possible explanation is that a different declaration of `productList` is in scope at the point you are seeing the `null`; e.g. it may be a local variable or a method parameter named `productList` that is *shadowing* the "global" declaration.

---

Note that a variable in Java *cannot* magically become `null` if it was previously non-null.  Either something assigned to it, or it is a different variable.  There are no other plausible explanations ... assuming that you are using pure Java.